# mac magic keyboard on windows in intellij key binding

Tags: windows, macos, intellij-idea, keyboard

I have been using intellij on mac for the last 4 years, now using windows temporarily, and expect to return to mac soon.

I bought a magic keyboard for my windows machine so I wouldnt have to (re)learn 2 sets of keyboard shortcuts, and i switched intellij layout to mac default, but this does not work as I expected. The mac keyboard is pretending to be a windows keyboard rather than just being a mac keyboard.

Is there a simple way to tell the magic keyboard to just be a mac keyboard? I want all keyboard shortcuts to be exactly the same.

Ive googled this for a bit but found nothing helpful.

I looked into microsoft keyboard layout creator, but it appears the windows key will always be a windows key, and windows will never see a command or option key. This may be a viable solution, but looks like a time suck, and I'd like to know if anybody has suggestions before I go down this route any further.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try making Windows key to act as Meta:

1. Press `Help | Edit Custom Properties...` (if a dialog appears, press "Create")
2. "idea.properties" file will open. Add `keymap.windows.as.meta=true` to a new line
3. Restart IDE

Comment: If that won't help, take a look at [this solution](https://www.kapresoft.com/java/2018/09/03/using-apple-keyboard-on-windows-intellij.html) through AutoHotkey.